# Como poner titulo de un Listview en un bubble de Android

Tags: android

Necesito colocar la fecha como`título de un Listview` pero dentro de un `bubble`, alguien me podria decir como hacerlo.

Aqui el codigo para colocar la `fecha como título:`

```
    readFechaActual();
    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(stringDate);
    listView.addHeaderView(textView);
```

Con este codigo obtengo esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero lo que necesito es un titulo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí el archivo para crear el bubble:
`drawable/time_message.xml:`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/SALMON" />
<corners android:radius="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [setBackgroundResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)) para establecer el estilo programaticamente, quedaria de esta forma:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.time_message);
```

Con lo referente a tu estilo `shape` puedes agregarle un `padding`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <padding
        android:bottom="16dp"
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:top="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>
```

Puedes ir jugando con el `padding` a tu conveniencia.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizar varias opciones, primeramente crea tu fondo

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
 <shape android:shape="rectangle">
 <solid android:color="@color/SALMON"/>
 <corners android:radius="20dp" />
 </shape>
</item>
</selector>
```

definelo como fondo a tu `TextView` en el layout :

```
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/myTextView"
 ...
 ...
 android:background="@drawable/fondo_redondo"

 />
```

También puedes definir el fondo programaticamente:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fondo_redondo);
```

tendrías como resultado algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]